# How do I determine if a field is empty or null in a Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-devtools, isnull, is-empty

My objective is to determine if a field called `name` is empty.
My code is returning this error:

> "object is not a function'.

This is resolved because I initially used `(name)` not `[name]` in the `if`statement

```
function notEmptyOrNull() {
    var name1 = "Sherlock";
    var name2 = "Watson";
    var name3 = "";

    var namesArray= ["Ben", "Lucy", "Watson", "Sherlock"];

    if  (namesArray[name1] !== null) {  // resolved error

        console.log(name1);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
notEmptyOrNull();
```

Updated the code:
`if (namesArray(name)` to `if (namesArray[name]` which resolved the error.

But when I tested for `name3` which I have changed to an 'empty string' = ""

How do I do this ?

In Chrome Dev Tools I would like to see output as true or false for each.

I would also like to output the data of each field.

Again, this is rather simple but I am still sorting this out.

I know that I'm missing sections of the code to accomplish this.

Comment: An array is not a function, you can't do `namesArray()` (except in old IE), you do `namesArray[name1]` !

Comment: And you probably want `if ( namesArray.indexOf(name1) === -1 )` anyway

Comment: wow. that was quick and an easy fix.  I am trying to do this for name2 which i renamed with a typo to return false. thanks.

Comment: @adeneo  you said this "And you probably want if ( namesArray.indexOf(name1) === -1 ) anyway "  and yes I do want to make use of indexOf().  But when I used this code, I am not getting any output in the console !

Answer (score 1):

What about `namesArray.indexOf(name1) > -1`  Like this you are not checking for null, you are checking if the value exist in the array

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the array values wrongly. The "()" are used for calling functions, to get an element from an array you have to use "[]"

Like this:

```
if  (namesArray[name1] !== null) {
```

P.D. In fact what I think that you want is to find if the name is INSIDE the array, in which case you should use this method:

```
if (namesArray.indexOf(name1) !== -1)
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: wont this still fail as it's not an associative array. There needs to be an indexOf function to search the array.

Comment: @adeneo  This thread took a turn.  My original question was to test ' if name is null'.  The thread began to suggest ways to test 'if name exists in the array.  Your original response is correct but I cannot click on an arrow to upVote your answer.  also.  When I change this field to be an empty string   name1 = ""   I am 'not returning -1 or false in the console.'  Do you or does anyone know why ?

Comment: @JLRishe hi.  if you have a chance can you view this post, especially the post directly above this one by me.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Replace:

```
 if  (namesArray(name1) !== null) { ...
```

With:

```
 if  (name1.indexOf(namesArray) !== -1 ) { ...
```

Array.indexOf() will return -1 if the element can't be fount in the array or else, the index of the element inside the array (where 0 represents the first element).